# UIAlertView and memory leak

Tags: objective-c, ios

```
UIAlertView* av = [UIAlertView alloc];

int a = [self somefunc];
if (a == 1) 
{
    [[av initWithTitle:nil message:@"test msg 1" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
} 
else if (a == 2) 
{
    [[av initWithTitle:nil message:@"test msg 2" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
} 

[av release];
```

when I run anlyze on this code i am getting the error "refence counted object is used after it is released" at line `[av release];`

can I know, where av got released, does show function of UIAlertView released av?

**strangly the below code doesnt show any error when analyze tool is used**

```
if (a == 1) 
{

    UIAlertView* av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"test msg 1" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [av show];
    [av release];
} 

else if (a == 2) 
{
    UIAlertView* av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"test msg 1" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [av show];
    [av release];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must always use the return value of any `init` call, because an `init` function can return a different value. Therefore, if you really want to separate `alloc` and `init` then you have to do it like this:

```
UIAlertView *av = [UIAlertView alloc];
// ...
av = [av initWithTitle:...]; // Might change the value of av !!
[av show];
[av release];
```

The "spurious release" in your code happens here:

```
[av initWithTitle:...]
```

because that might (as explained above) release `av` and return a different object.

Answer (score 1):

In your first code the object "av" is not sure to be initialized, what if the value of a is not 1 0r 2? av will not be initialized so when your release it there will be some problems.

In your second code av's scope became more specific or local to the conditions of if and else. Thats why xcode is sure that av will be initialized and it is safe to relese av.

Comment: u r answering only part of it I feel, in my first code can I know why analyze tool is giving the error "refence counted object is used after it is released"

Answer (score 0):

`show` function is not releasing the `UIAlertView` if it is the question here (in the second code).

Comment: can I know why analyze tool is giving the error "refence counted object is used after it is released"

Comment: in case of the first or second snippet?